# iPhone won't stop connecting to bluetooth, interferes with mouse

Tags: iphone, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

My iPhone keeps pairing itself to my Mac. I know because every time it happens my mouse lags horribly until I remove it.

Things I've tried:

- Reset the Bluetooth module
- Factory reset all connected Apple devices
- Remove all devices
- Select device > remove device

When it happens, it is only listed in the Bluetooth menu item; it's not listed in `System Preferences > Bluetooth`.

Until recently I had an app called Typeeto installed which enabled me to use my Bluetooth keyboard on any other device without unpairing and re-pairing. Basically, it transmits to the Mac, which transmits to the device. I believe this is the root cause and I removed the paired devices from it and deleted it. Still no luck.

Comment: If you sign out of iCloud on either the computer or on the phone, does that immediately remedy the situation?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Deleting the com.apple.bluetooth files in /Library/Preferences and ~/Library/Preferences seems to have taken care of it.